# Travel to Bhutan Through Bangkok Airport Transit

Tags: transit-visas, bkk, fijian-citizens

My Question is I am Travelling to Paro, Bhutan through Bangkok, The flight arrives into Bangkok at 22.10 on 19/08/19 and out of Bangkok to Paro, Bhutan is at 6.30am on 20/08/19. bangkok - Bhutan is Bhutan Airlines B3 701

Please kindly confirm if visa is required for that 8hrs and 20 mins layover into Bangkok.

The passport holder is from Fiji.

Comment: Actually one piece of info is missing, what is the carrier taking you from origin to Bangkok? There are some airlines exempted from the TWOV (transit without visa).

Answer (score 2):

According to [timatic](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) (the software used to determine documents needed) you may transit through Bangkok, Thailand **without** a visa *if* your transit is for less than 12 h. So you should be all good! Enjoy your trip!